# Delete down voted question

Tags: discussion, downvotes, deleted-questions

Pretty simple question, really...
I raised a couple of questions that received some down votes due to too broad, opinion based, etc. Basically nobody answered them and there's probably nothing useful for others in them.

Should I delete these down voted questions?

*One would think this has been asked before and I'm sure it has; however, the only thing I found was referring to downvoted answers.*

Comment: Deleted questions still count against you in calculations of a possible question ban. So no, you shouldn't delete them, but edit and improve them, or simply wait until they get deleted by the community, or the ROOMBA script.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: If they aren't being salvaged, reducing the further drain on the community and on his status by deleting himself is certainly a good idea. Just beware of being over-sensitive. Naturally, salvaging them is far preferable.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ , What's ROOMBA?

Comment: @CoolGuy See here please: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006

Comment: I agree with both @πάνταῥεῖ and Deduplicator. if you yourself feel that it can be edited and made into a better question, then do that and wait for a new answer. But, if even you feel it is totally useless, Delete it, an unanswered question that is too broad or opinion based will not be of much use unless it is edited and improved. But don't delete too many questions ( that will give you a question ban ).

Comment: Thanks, guys, that's really helpful stuff. Wish I would have known some of it earlier, I already deleted some - I hope it didn't affect my account too much in a negative way. I won't delete them in the future, but try to salvage them no matter what.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Do you have any evidence that self-deleted questions factor into the question ban any differently than roomba-deleted or community-deleted ones? I wouldn't expect a difference.

Comment: @AndrewMedico SE has never said that there's a difference; I wouldn't expect there to be one.

Comment: @AndrewMedico To be honest, no I have no evidence for this. It was merely an assumption this will be handled differently by the engine (for reasons of fairness).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can (and are willing to) improve the questions such that they are no longer inappropriate and of low quality, then doing so is far preferable to deleting them.

If you can't/won't improve the questions, and there is no valuable content within them (such as a quality answer), then you might as well delete the questions.

Just keep in mind that if you continue to provide low quality content and don't take this learning opportunity to improve the quality of your future contributions, you may end up being unable to ask questions.  This applies whether or not you delete the content.