# Should I delete my own down-voted question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I asked a question and posted an answer to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17224881/1467396) quite a while ago.  As noted there, I made the post simply because Internet searches weren't turning anything up that could fix my problem, so when I finally DID find the solution, I documented here on SO, hoping to save someone else some time.  It wasn't long, however and the question was down-voted.

Now, I realize that's it was a pretty obscure problem and that the solution was almost "too simple", but if you Google that error message today ("cannot unregister type library - cannot load file, check to make sure it's a valid type library"), my post is not only the top result, but it is also the 3rd result because another site simply copied my question and answer (note that the 2nd result would not have worked for my scenario).

I still feel like my original post adds some value to SO, but apparently the consensus of everyone else that looked at it is that it does not (and thus it has a total score of -1).  My desire is to be a good SO citizen so...

**Here are my questions:**

1. **In general**, should I delete my questions that are not well received (have a negative score), even if I think they are useful?
2. **For [my original post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17224881/1467396)**, Is this really a bad question, or did the one person who voted make a bad vote? (note that he/she did not leave any comments, so I'm not sure what I did wrong).

As a bonus, and since we're on the topic of deleting one's own down-voted questions anyway, I'm also wondering if having this question with a net score < 0 will affect my ability to earn badges such as [curious](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4127/curious) (what exactly does "and maintained a positive question record" mean?  Are NONE of my questions allowed to have a negative score, or just the ones during that time period? Is asking a question with a negative score a final thing, or will deleting my post "fix" it?  Stuff like that...).

---

In searching Meta, I found these similar questions, but I feel my question is different (not a duplicate) for the reasons listed:

[Should I delete (my own) unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280888/should-i-delete-my-own-unanswered-questions) --> different because unanswered questions aren't necessarily down-voted

[Should I delete my own downvoted answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263046/should-i-delete-my-own-downvoted-answer) --> unlike a down-voted answer which can provide insight into what NOT to do, a down vote on a question (to me) means "you shouldn't have bothered us with that question."

[When is deleting a question good, and when is it bad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276230/when-is-deleting-a-question-good-and-when-is-it-bad) --> the accepted answer here is that you should fix the question, not delete it.  However, as noted, I'm really not sure what's wrong with my post and so I don't know how to improve it.

[Is it bad form to delete a question with downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267989/is-it-bad-form-to-delete-a-question-with-downvotes) --> same

[Delete down voted question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287195/delete-down-voted-question) --> The OP states that "Basically nobody answered them and there's probably nothing useful for others in them," which is not the case here.

Comment: First, there is only one downvote on that post. That does not necessarily indicate consensus. Second, it could partially be how your post was formatted. I have offered up an edit that you may reject if you feel it does not fit right.

Comment: As for the badge part, it will not prevent you from ever gettting the badge. Overall, your questions need to be well-received. One negatively scored post will not ruin that for you.

Comment: @Kendra: thanks, I think that does look nicer.